# how to clear the strings when sending request to url

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP to generating the xml. I'm sending the request to each url to get the strings of hours so I can convert it to format date like `20140425130000`, but I have a problem with the loops. When I converting the hours to format date, for each format I have put it in each start="" which it should have different input, but I have got the same input in each start="". I have tried to use $html_two->clear() to clear the format in each time when I send request to each url, so I would have each different input of format at a time without get the same input over and over.

Here is the input format:

```
20140425130000
20140425130000
20140425125800
```

Here is the xml output:

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140425130000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>

<channel id="102 Animal Planet">
<display-name>102 Animal Planet</display-name>
<programme channel="107 Animal Planet" start="20140425130000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>

<channel id="111 BRAVO USA">
<display-name>111 BRAVO USA</display-name>
<programme channel="111 BRAVO USA" start="20140425130000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
</tv>
```

Here is what it should be looks like:

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140425130000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>

<channel id="102 Animal Planet">
<display-name>102 Animal Planet</display-name>
<programme channel="107 Animal Planet" start="20140425130000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>

<channel id="111 BRAVO USA">
<display-name>111 BRAVO USA</display-name>
<programme channel="111 BRAVO USA" start="20140425125800" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
</tv>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

function getState($string)
{
  $ex = explode(" ",$string);
  return $ex[1];
}

$xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$xml .= '
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';
$base1 = "http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php";
$html = file_get_html($base1);      

foreach($html->find('p[id=links]') as $element)
{
  $program_list[ $count ] = array();
  $id_split = explode("?", $element->plaintext);
  $id_split = explode("&", $link_split[1]);
  $channels = explode("channels=",$id_split[0]);
  $channels = $channels[1];
  $id = explode("id=",$id_split[1]);
  $id = $id[1];

  //channels
  //$channel_test = $html->find('p[id=channels]', 10)->plaintext;
  //echo $channel_test;

  $program_list[ $count ]['channels'] = $channels;
  $program_list[ $count ]['id'] = $id;

  $channels_split = explode("?", $element->plaintext);
  $channels_split = explode("&", $channels_split[1]);
  $channel_id = explode("channels=",$channels_split[0]);
  $channel_id = $channel_id[1];
  $my_id = explode("id=",$channels_split[1]);
  $my_id = $my_id[1];

  $channel = urlencode($channel_id);
  $id_1 = urlencode($my_id);
  $html_two = file_get_html("http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php?channels=" . $channel . "&id=" . $my_id);
  $time1 = $html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext;
  $time2 = $html_two->find('span[id=time2]',0)->plaintext;
  $time3 = $html_two->find('span[id=time3]',0)->plaintext;
  $time4 = $html_two->find('span[id=time4]',0)->plaintext;
  $time5 = $html_two->find('span[id=time5]',0)->plaintext;
  $time6 = $html_two->find('span[id=time6]',0)->plaintext;
  $time7 = $html_two->find('span[id=time7]',0)->plaintext;
  $time8 = $html_two->find('span[id=time8]',0)->plaintext;
  $time9 = $html_two->find('span[id=time9]',0)->plaintext;
  $time10 = $html_two->find('span[id=time10]',0)->plaintext;
  $time11 = $html_two->find('span[id=time11]',0)->plaintext;
  $time12 = $html_two->find('span[id=time12]',0)->plaintext;
  $time13 = $html_two->find('span[id=time13]',0)->plaintext;
  $time14 = $html_two->find('span[id=time14]',0)->plaintext;
  $time15 = $html_two->find('span[id=time15]',0)->plaintext;
  $time16 = $html_two->find('span[id=time16]',0)->plaintext;
  $time17 = $html_two->find('span[id=time17]',0)->plaintext;


  $array = array(
    $time1,
    $time2,
    $time3,
    $time4,
    $time5,
    $time6,
    $time7,
    $time8,
    $time9,
    $time10,
    $time11,
    $time12,
    $time13,
    $time14,
    $time15,
    $time16,
    $time17,
  );

  // Save the output format
  $DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "YmdHis";

  // GET the current STAGE
  $current_state = getState($array[0]);
  $offset = 0;
  $time_1 = array();
  $time_2 = array();
  $time_3 = array();
  $time_4 = array();
  $time_5 = array();
  $time_6 = array();
  $time_7 = array();
  $time_8 = array();         
  $time_9 = array();
  $time_10 = array();  

  foreach($array as $time)
  {
    // Get the item state.  
    $this_state = getState($time);

    // check if we past a day? 
    if($current_state == "PM" && $this_state == "AM")
    {
      $offset++;
    }
    $this_unix1 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix2 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix3 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix4 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix5 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix6 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix7 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix8 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix9 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix10 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);

    $time_1[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix1);
    $time_2[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix2);
    $time_3[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix3);
    $time_4[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix4);
    $time_5[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix5);
    $time_6[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix6);
    $time_7[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix7);
    $time_8[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix8);
    $time_9[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix9);
    $time_10[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix10);
  }
  $program_list[$count]['start_time1'] = $time_1[0];
  $count++;
  $current_state = $this_state;


  if (strpos($channel, '+') !== false)
  {
    $channel = str_replace('+', ' ', $channel);
  }

  //program 1#
  $xml .= "
  <channel id='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "'>";
  $xml .= "
    <display-name>" . $my_id. " " . $channel; 
  $xml .= "</display-name>";
  $xml .= "
  <programme channel='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "' start='" . $program_list[$i]['start_time1'] . "' stop='" . $program_list[$i]['end_time1'] . "'>";
  $xml .= '
    <title lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </title>';
  $xml .= '
    <sub-title lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </sub-title>';
  $xml .= '
    <desc lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </desc>';
  $xml .= '
    <category lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </category>';
  $xml .= "
  </programme>";
  $xml .= '
  </channel>';
}

//Clear DOM object
$html_two->clear();
unset($html_two);

$xml .= '
</tv>';
//output the xml to the browser, write $xml to a file here...
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $xml;
$handle = fopen("myChannel.xml", "w"); 
fwrite ($handle, $xml);
?>
```

Does anyone know how I can get each different input of format in each time when I send the request to url to get the format at a time while I clear them so I would not get the same input of format when I input them in each start=""?

**Edit: It will start to show the input format in each start="", but at the start of the xml it will show as empty input which you can see this:**

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
<channel id="102 CBS">
<display-name>102 CBS</display-name>
<programme channel="102 CBS" start="20140425140000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
<channel id="103 CNN USA">
<display-name>103 CNN USA</display-name>
<programme channel="103 CNN USA" start="20140425140000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
<channel id="105 ESPN USA">
<display-name>105 ESPN USA</display-name>
<programme channel="105 ESPN USA" start="20140425140000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
<channel id="106 Fox News">
<display-name>106 Fox News</display-name>
<programme channel="106 Fox News" start="20140425150000" stop="">
<title lang="en"></title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
</tv>
```

Here is the update code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

function getState($string)
{
  $ex = explode(" ",$string);
  return $ex[1];
}

$xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$xml .= '
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';
$base1 = "http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php";
$html = file_get_html($base1);      
$i = 0;

foreach($html->find('p[id=links]') as $element)
{
  $program_list[ $count ] = array();
  $id_split = explode("?", $element->plaintext);
  $id_split = explode("&", $link_split[1]);
  $channels = explode("channels=",$id_split[0]);
  $channels = $channels[1];
  $id = explode("id=",$id_split[1]);
  $id = $id[1];

  //channels
  //$channel_test = $html->find('p[id=channels]', 10)->plaintext;
  //echo $channel_test;

  $program_list[ $count ]['channels'] = $channels;
  $program_list[ $count ]['id'] = $id;

  $channels_split = explode("?", $element->plaintext);
  $channels_split = explode("&", $channels_split[1]);
  $channel_id = explode("channels=",$channels_split[0]);
  $channel_id = $channel_id[1];
  $my_id = explode("id=",$channels_split[1]);
  $my_id = $my_id[1];

  $channel = urlencode($channel_id);
  $id_1 = urlencode($my_id);
  $html_two = file_get_html("http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php?channels=" . $channel . "&id=" . $my_id);
  $time1 = $html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext;
  $time2 = $html_two->find('span[id=time2]',0)->plaintext;
  $time3 = $html_two->find('span[id=time3]',0)->plaintext;
  $time4 = $html_two->find('span[id=time4]',0)->plaintext;
  $time5 = $html_two->find('span[id=time5]',0)->plaintext;
  $time6 = $html_two->find('span[id=time6]',0)->plaintext;
  $time7 = $html_two->find('span[id=time7]',0)->plaintext;
  $time8 = $html_two->find('span[id=time8]',0)->plaintext;
  $time9 = $html_two->find('span[id=time9]',0)->plaintext;
  $time10 = $html_two->find('span[id=time10]',0)->plaintext;
  $time11 = $html_two->find('span[id=time11]',0)->plaintext;
  $time12 = $html_two->find('span[id=time12]',0)->plaintext;
  $time13 = $html_two->find('span[id=time13]',0)->plaintext;
  $time14 = $html_two->find('span[id=time14]',0)->plaintext;
  $time15 = $html_two->find('span[id=time15]',0)->plaintext;
  $time16 = $html_two->find('span[id=time16]',0)->plaintext;
  $time17 = $html_two->find('span[id=time17]',0)->plaintext;


  $array = array(
    $time1,
    $time2,
    $time3,
    $time4,
    $time5,
    $time6,
    $time7,
    $time8,
    $time9,
    $time10,
    $time11,
    $time12,
    $time13,
    $time14,
    $time15,
    $time16,
    $time17,
  );

  // Save the output format
  $DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "YmdHis";

  // GET the current STAGE
  $current_state = getState($array[0]);
  $offset = 0;
  $time_1 = array();
  $time_2 = array();
  $time_3 = array();
  $time_4 = array();
  $time_5 = array();
  $time_6 = array();
  $time_7 = array();
  $time_8 = array();         
  $time_9 = array();
  $time_10 = array();  

  foreach($array as $time)
  {
    // Get the item state.  
    $this_state = getState($time);

    // check if we past a day? 
    if($current_state == "PM" && $this_state == "AM")
    {
      $offset++;
    }
    $this_unix1 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix2 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix3 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix4 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix5 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix6 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix7 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix8 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix9 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);
    $this_unix10 = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);

    $time_1[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix1);
    $time_2[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix2);
    $time_3[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix3);
    $time_4[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix4);
    $time_5[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix5);
    $time_6[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix6);
    $time_7[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix7);
    $time_8[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix8);
    $time_9[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix9);
    $time_10[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix10);
  }
  $program_list[$count]['start_time1'] = $time_1[0];
  $count++;
  $current_state = $this_state;

  if (strpos($channel, '+') !== false)
  {
    $channel = str_replace('+', ' ', $channel);
  }

  //program 1#
  $xml .= "
  <channel id='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "'>";
  $xml .= "
    <display-name>" . $my_id. " " . $channel; 
  $xml .= "</display-name>";
  $xml .= "
  <programme channel='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "' start='" . $program_list[$i]['start_time1'] . "' stop='" . $program_list[$i]['end_time1'] . "'>";
  $xml .= '
    <title lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </title>';
  $xml .= '
    <sub-title lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </sub-title>';
  $xml .= '
    <desc lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </desc>';
  $xml .= '
    <category lang="en">';
  $xml .= ' </category>';
  $xml .= "
  </programme>";
  $xml .= '
  </channel>';
  $i++;
}

//Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);

$xml .= '
</tv>';
//output the xml to the browser, write $xml to a file here...
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $xml;
$handle = fopen("myChannel.xml", "w"); 
fwrite ($handle, $xml);
?>
```

Comment: You never set `$i` to anything, so in best case it is always `0`.

Comment: Oh right, so do I need to use something like this? `$xml .= "
  <programme channel='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "' start='" . $program_list[0]['start_time1'] . "' stop='" . $program_list[$i]['end_time1'] . "'>";`?

Comment: No, you need to increment `$i` on every iteration of the foreach loop.

Comment: can you please post the code for `$i` on every iteration of the foreach loop?

Comment: Set it to 0 first, then add `$i++;` to the end of the loop.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't get it. can you please post the code which it will be much easier for me to understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;

foreach($html->find('p[id=links]') as $element)
{
    // your init codes

    // program 1#
    // your xml

    // at the end of the loop, increase $i by 1
    $i++;

}
```

Otherwise, `$i` will remain the same value on every loop, but you do not want to print the same `start_time1` over and over again.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I can see that it is working now but I have got a problem. At the start of the xml the start="" is show as empty input which i have the input for the format. I guess that my code must be wrong. Do you know why the start="" is show as the empty input? I have updated the code for you to take a look.

Comment: Do you initialise `$count` somewhere? If not, set it to 0 after `$time_10 = array();` or try to set `$i` to 1 at the beginning.

Comment: yes I do have the $count after the `foreach($html->find`. Do I need to set the $offset to 1 instead of 0? what do you mean by set it to 0 after the `$time10 = array();`? there are no value after the `$time10 = array();` in my code list.

Comment: You never initialise `$count` in the script you've posted. You just use it. First occurance is in line 22 and `$count` becomes an index of the `$program_list` array. Whatever is the initial value of `$count` must also be the initial value of `$i`. Usually you start counting at 0.

Comment: oh ok so do I need to replace the $count to $i in line 22?

Comment: Na, for the ease of use, try to add a `$count = 0;` at line 19 after `$i = 0;`.

Comment: I got it now everything is working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help which it much appreciated. :)